# How to generate an URL with Pyramid and Akhet?

Tags: python, url, pylons, pyramid, akhet

I'm creating an [Akhet](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/akhet/dev/index.html) (Pyramid) web application. 
How can one generate in a mako template the URL for a given Handler/view ?

I'm looking for the equivalent of Pylons' `${url(controller="users", view="list")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akhet exposes the `URLGenerator` object as a renderer global, so you can just use `url('users', action='list')`, assuming `config.add_handler('users', '/users/{action}', ...)` in your setup.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/akhet/dev/api.html#module-akhet.urlgenerator

Comment: I don't see where it's written in the page you linked but url(handler, action="someaction") works. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use route_url. It's available in the templates in request.route_url.

```
<a href="${request.route_url('import')}">Import</a>
```

for example

Comment: it indeed works. It took me some time to understand your answer, which is not complete. In the case of akhet, assuming config.add_handler('users', '/users/{action}', ...) in the setup as Michael said, you can call: request.route_url('users', action='someaction').  To obtain a relative path (without http://), the method to call is route_path instead of route_url.